# Doing a for loop within a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to a do for loop like (for int x = 0; x < 3; x++) in a django template. How should I do it? 
Pseudo code looks like the following:

```
{% for Summary in Summary_list %}
        {% ifchanged Summary.bu_id %}
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>{{Summary.bu.version}}</td>
            {% if Summary.platform_id != 1 %}
                {% for x less than Summary.platform_id %}
                        <td><center>-</center></td>
                        {% x++ %}
```

{# How Should I do this part? #}

```
            <td> <center>{{Summary.successCount}}</center></td>
        {% else %}
            <td><center> {{Summary.successCount}}</center></td>
        {% endifchanged %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible repeat of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates

Answer (score 0):

Use the template range filter in this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/).  (For background on using custom filters consult the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags).)

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
{% for x in Summary.platform_id|get_range %}

...

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one more question. I need to declare a variable to store a number retrieved from the template. I know that I cannot declare a variable in the template but in the view. How should I declare it in the views? And how can I update the value when 
{% for Summary in Summary_list %} updates??
Thank you!!

Comment: There's no good way to do this, since logic is for views and templates are only for presentation.  It seems though that any information available to a template is available to a view.  For example, you have access to Summary_list in the view.  So you should be able to do what you need without retrieving a parameter from the template.