# Django, simplest forloop, how? (i=0; i<20; i++)

Tags: django, for-loop

I just need to generate some test content for my template. Something like:

```
{{ for i < 20 }}
<img src="image-{{i}}.jpg " />
{{ endfor }}
```

I have no list, how should I proceed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it stucks up if you don't have a list or a iterable on template. DJango doesn't provide a default way to write dummy data. But it does provide `lorem` tag to get some dummy text. See [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/webdesign/).

But you can do an exercise though to get working what exactly you are trying to do.
Create a custom templatetag, as `myutilities.py` and add to `templatetags` directory of your `app`.

```
from django import template        
register = template.Library()  

@register.filter  
def range(value):  
    return range(value)
```

Template

```
{% load myutilities %}  
{% for i in 50|range %}  
   {{ forloop.counter }}<img src="image-{{i}}.jpg " />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

[http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/779/](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/)

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/