# Is there a Django template language equivalent to Python’s range()?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numeric for loop in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates)

In Python, if I want to run a loop nine times, I can do:

```
for i in range(1,10):
```

Is there an equivalent for the `{% for %}` tag in Django’s template language?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates) question.

Basically there is no support for it directly and you will need to write your own template tag for it or add it to the context your self.  Either way isn't too big of a deal.