# how to loop 7 times in the django templates

Tags: django, templates

this is my code :

```
{% for i in range(7)%}
        <option value={{i+1}}> {{i+1}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

but it show error ,

what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates same question?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

views.py:

```
context['loop_times'] = range(1, 8)
```

html:

```
{% for i in loop_times %}
        <option value={{ i }}>{{ i }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1: Best to put this in the view, but `range(1, 8)` would be much cleaner.

Comment: Why not just pass the range?
view:
  context['loop_range'] = range(1, 8)
template:
  {% for i in loop_range %}
    ...
  {% endfor %}

Comment: Love the simplicity, thank you.  Bizarre that something so simple isn't supported in templates.

Comment: My question is, how do I add this getting for example user posts? I need to loop only three posts from users so how would I add the range within the view? For example ``` posts = Post.objects.all()```. Then in templates ```{% post in posts:"3" %}```. That is my approach but for my limited understanding I am not finding a clear answer.

Answer (score 55):

In python strings are iterables so this works :

```
{% for i in "1234567" %}
    <option value={{i}}> {{i}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

It's explicit, so quite OK, but zjm1126's answer is probably better for long term consideration.

Comment: Very useful for prototyping, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django templates don't support ranges. You have a couple options:

1. Add a range filter: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/

Here's how you add custom filters: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

1. Use a different templating system, like Mako, that does support it.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-an-alternative-template-language
Django-Mako is a shortcut project for using Mako: http://code.google.com/p/django-mako/