# Why this example do not leave

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Here's a link to this page https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5172

To be more specific this

```
{% for 5 %}
repeat me
{% endfor %}
```

and  this

```
{% for my_integer %}
loop: {{ forloop.counter }}
{% endfor %}
```

mistakes that I earn is following

```
TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements should have at least four words: for 5
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this:

```
{% for i in 5|getrange %}
do something
{% endfor %}
```

See [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/) code snippet.

Comment: That requires adding the code to implement that filter, before it can be used.

Comment: @Amber Django templates don't support range functions though - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5242907/1907098

Comment: In rewriting the filter I get the following error
TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for i
0 to 5

Comment: @Krasimir Firstly, what's your filter? Secondly, you're meant to type `{% for i in 5|yourfilter %}`

Comment: {% load range_tags %}
    <ul>{% for i in 3|get_range %}
      <li>{{ i }}. Do something</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul>

This code is not working and you start.

Here's the filter

from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter
def get_range(value):

    return range( value )

Comment: @Krasimir everything should work fine, not sure what the problem here is

Comment: The problem is that it does not recognize django html comments and gave me error commented cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to is a ticket requesting such syntax. It is closed as `wontfix`, as in, that functionality is very specifically *not* available and unlikely to be added any time soon.

Instead, you'd need to use something like `{% for counter in my_range %}` or similar, where `my_range` is set to the output of `range(5)`.