# How to access a dictionary in a list in Django Template?

Tags: django, templates

In my views.py i have :

```
credits_total = Course.objects.filter(dept = dept_code1, b_tech = 1, type = 1).values('sem').annotate(sum = Sum('credits'))
```

So credits_total has the following:

```
credits_total = [{'sem': 3, 'sum': 19},{'sem': 4, 'sum': 20},{'sem': 5, 'sum': 21},{'sem':6,'sum':22},{'sem':7,'sum':21},{'sem':8,'sum':24}]
```

I want to do somthing like:

```
{% for i in "012345" %}
    ....
    <b> {{credits_total[i]['sum']}} </b>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

How can i access a specific key in the dictionary at a specific index in the list?

I'm new to django so could you Plz explain in detail. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242866/how-to-loop-7-times-in-the-django-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:
In views.py:

```
    from itertools import izip_longest
    def course(request, dept_code):
    ....
    sum_credits_total = list()
    ....
    for i in credits_total: sum_credits_total.append(i['sum'])
    ....
    total_list  = izip_longest(sum_credits_total,hours_total,sum_sem_credits,sum_sem_hours)
    context_dict['total_list'] = total_list
    return render (request,'course.html', context_dict)
```

And in template:

```
    {% for i,j,k,l in total_list %}
         {{i}}....{{j}}....{{k}}....{{l}}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries are best thought of as [unordered sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so).  You shouldn't try to index them...  That said, you can [iterate over your dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template) data and print it as follows.

```
{% if credits_total %}
    {% for item in credits_total %}
        sem:{{ item.sem }}, sum:{{ item.sum }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: even this doesn't seem to give me the result. It doesn't give any value!

Comment: Are you seeing anything in credits_total at all?  maybe you are not passing the data correctly.  This works fine for me with your exact data.

Comment: to be exact i'm doing something like this in views.py: `context_dict['credits_total'] = credits_total` and `btech_list = zip(collapse_num,sem_title_btech,theory_btech,practical_btech,integers)
` where `integers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]` and`        context_dict['btech_list'] = btech_list
`and `    return render (request,'course.html', context_dict)
` then in django template `{% for i,j,k,l,m in btech_list %}
`.....` {{credits_total.m.sum}}`. But this doesn't give any data at all. It gives the results when i do `{{credits_total.1.sum}}` or with a direct input of any  other number.

Comment: Why are you trying to dump the `credits_total` dictionary by iterating through `btech_list`?  Simplify...  remove `btech_list` from the equation.  `credits_total` is a different object entirely and should be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

In template, you can use dot notation.
Like this:

```
<b>{{credits_total.i.sum}}</b>
```

But the problem with this is that `i` var inside the loop is not a number.
You need to write your own tag filter to get something like a regular `range()` in python.
See this: [create range filter](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/)

Comment: i tried it but the data doesn't show up neither does it throw any error!!

Comment: i tried to hard code it by replacing i with 0. it still doesn't work!

Comment: I tried this using numbers instead of i, and it worked for me. `{{credits_total.1.sum}}`

Comment: to be exact i'm doing something like this in views.py: `context_dict['credits_total'] = credits_total` and `btech_list = zip(collapse_num,sem_title_btech,theory_btech,practical_btech,integers)
` where `integers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]` and`        context_dict['btech_list'] = btech_list
`and `    return render (request,'course.html', context_dict)
` then in django template `{% for i,j,k,l,m in btech_list %}
`.....` {{credits_total.m.sum}}`. But this doesn't give any data at all. It gives the results when i do `{{credits_total.1.sum}}`. Now m is a set of int values, but still it doesn't give the data!