# Loop based on range in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates) that is similar to my one but not the same, so I ask about it here.
Assume, I have an SELECT with a list of OPTION elements that I want to fill with years, for example, from 1920 to current year. How can I start iterating not from zero to some value but from some value to some another value? For example, from 1920 to 2011?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `range(1920, 2012)` from the view.