# Django: 'long' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

1. I have a model

   ```
   class tournaments(models.Model):
       # ....
       total_rounds = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
       # ....

       def get_total_rounds_count(self):
           return self.total_rounds
   ```
2. views.py:

   ```
   def tourney_view(request, offset):
       # .....
       if (offset):
           selected_tournament =  tournaments.objects.get(id=offset)
       return render_to_response('tournament.html', {'tournament': selected_tournament})
   ```
3. In 'tournament.html' template i trying to loop over total_rounds:

   ```
   {% for q in tournament.get_total_rounds_count%}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

And got error: 'long' object is not iterable
Why? My field is IntegerField, and i am simply trying to loop over integer values, but get "not iterable"

Comment: For future posts: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: And what does `tournament.get_total_rounds_count` return? (As I suspect Otto is right here...)

Comment: It returns self.total_rounds - integer value

Comment: @Rusty: 'long' is python's unbounded integer format; it is basically the same. What Jon was trying to say is that the error message is expected.

Comment: See [Numeric for loop in Django templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/

Or define `Tournament.get_total_rounds` which returns `range(get_total_rounds_count)`

Comment: when i trying to use "range" i get error from django parser:Could not parse the remainder: '(tournament.get_total_rounds_count)' from 'range(tournament.get_total_rounds_count)'

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Otto's way is best, just update your function to return the range.

```
 class tournaments(models.Model):
     # ....
     total_rounds = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
     # ....

     def get_total_rounds_count(self):
         return range(self.total_rounds)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't use `for` construction with numbers

Comment: And what should i do if i want to loop over "total_rounds " ?

Comment: @Rusty: You can't loop over numbers; you *can* create a loop that iterates a "total_rounds" number of times, but that's a different concept..

Comment: Is there some way to use "range(tournament.get_total_rounds_count)" or something equal in django template?