# how to include a template n times in django?

Tags: python, django, partial

I would like to include a partial n times in a django app (I am new to/learning django). I am more experienced in rails, where I would simply write:

```
 <% 3.times do %>
    render 'feeds/feature'
 <% end %>
```

I would like to know how to do something similar in django. Here is what I thought to do:

```
 {% i = 1%}
 {% for i =< 9 %}
   {% include 'feeds/feature.html'%}
   {% i += 1%}
 {% end %}
```

This, however, does not work - i get a template syntax error Invalid block tag: 'i', expected 'endblock'

Can I embed python into a django page like I do in rails? And, more importantly, how would I include the feature.html page n (or in this case 9) times in django?

Comment: Partal duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put range in the context from the view and then:

In the view:

```
render_to_response('foo.html', {..., 'range': range(9), ...}, ...)
```

In the template:

```
{% for i in range %}
    {% include 'feeds/feature.html'%}
{% endfor %}
```

Also you can do something like that:

```
{% for i in "123456789" %}
    {% include 'feeds/feature.html'%}
{% endfor %}
```

Yes, very ugly.

Or you can define template tag:

[Snipet 1](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/779/)

[Snipet 2](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something but I can not imagine a situation were I would need it this way. If you have a feature list from database and want to display some specific amount of them, you can do this by:

```
{% for feature in feature_list|slice:":3" %}
    {% include "template.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or simply write three includes beneath. But as I said, this is not a common programming pattern, there can be a better solution.