# Python for loop in Django template syntax, iterate by 5

Tags: python, django-templates

I know this is an incredibly noob question but I can't seem to find an example of what I need (there's some for loop examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) but not what i need..

I can get this working using a simple script but the template syntax really throws me.

I need to simply add 10 to each iteration and just have a select list of multiples of ten.  However, I can't get even the following simple example to work:

```
<select id="multiples">
{% for num in range(5,100) %}
<option value="{{ num }}">{{ num }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Could anyone offer a hand please, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates don't work with arbitrary code. Django's built-in `for` loops don't support this sort of thing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates) is a previous discussion with some good options on how to get the sort of behavior you want.

Comment: @rix: The easiest "quick fix" is probably to generate the range on the backend, and just pass it as a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's range third argument (offset or increment). You can set it to skip certain elements:

```
 >>> range(0, 10, 3)
 [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Edit-----

As you know, Django templates don't understand ranges. So, the option would be to pass either the range or the list itself from the backend. Passing the range would be something like:

```
render_to_response('template.html', {..., 'range': range(0, 10, 3), ...}, ...)
```

Comment: This is technically correct but doesn't address looping in django templates which doesn't allow for using the `range()` method.

Comment: YEs but you can either pass the range or the list from the backend

Comment: something like render_to_response('foo.html', {..., 'range': range(0, 10, 3), ...}, ...)

Comment: Right...so put it in the answer :)