# Is it possible to use Django forloop.counter in this case?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use a `Django forloop.counter` like this:

```
{% for i in "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" %}
    {{ i.time_code{{forloop.counter}} }}
{% endfor %}
```

Turns out, it's not possible to do that.

Reason to accomplish this. I have 20 database coloumns like: time_code1, time_code2 ....time_code20. So, instead of calling each separately I want to do this.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates

Answer (score 0):

I've used at in a similar way. Here is the example, don't know if it will help.

```
<form action= "{% url 'result_show' forloop.counter0 %}" method="post">
```

What it does is accepts the output of `forloop.counter0` as a parameter of a method in view. And it works that way.

Have you considered migrating the `time_code`s to a list and than accessing them via `forloop.counter`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question correctly. Do you want to retrieve attributes dynamically? You could write a custom tag:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_attr(obj, name, default=None):
    return getattr(obj, str(name), default)
```

then you can pass the list of attributes to your template:

```
attrs = ( "time_code"+str(i) for i in xrange(0, 100) )
return render_to_response("test.html", { "attrs": attrs })
```

and finally in your template:

```
{% for attr in attrs %}
    {% get_attr i attr %}
{% endfor %}
```