# how to set custom forloop start point in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

There is a forloop in java where i can tell where to start and where to end:

```
for(int i=10;i<array.length;i++){

}
```

but how can i implement this `int i=10` in django template? How can i set the starting and ending point on my own?

there is a `forloop.first` and `forloop.last`, but they are defined inside the loop and i cannot do something like this?:

```
{{forloop.first=10}}

{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}

{{forloop.last=20}}
```

I read the django doc but this feature seems to be not there

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @thomasorozco, just out of interest.

Comment: u can build a custom template tag which can do that for you, something like this http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/779/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using built-in [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice) filter:

```
{% for athlete in athlete_list|slice:"10:20" %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

If you need to make a numeric loop (just like python's `range`), you need a custom template tag, like this one: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1926/

See other `range` snippets:

- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2147/

Also see:

- [Numeric for loop in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates)

By the way, this doesn't sound like a job for templates - consider passing a range from the view. And, FYI, there was a [proposal](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13088) to make such tag, but it was rejected because `it is trying to lead to programming in the template.` - think about it.

Comment: my example was just an example code and not really mine. but the real question is: can i count from 2001 till 3001 in template in forloop?

Comment: I have a loop where the first item was styled a certain way, and subsequent items were styled differently. Doing so wrecked `divisibleby` as a way of adding clearfixes in Bootstrap, but this enabled me to do what I wanted. Thanks for the answer!