# How do I create this div id?

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to create a django template generated table.

How do I do this:

```
<div id="holder" onclick="dostuff()">
    <table id="table" bgcolor="{{s.color_hash}}">
        <tbody>
            {& for x in s.num_rows &}
                <tr id="r">
                    {& for y in s.num_columns &}
                        <td id="c" height='{{s.height}}' width='{{s.width}}'></td>
                    {& endfor &}
                </tr>
            {& endfor &}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Where the `<tr id="r">` I would like to have the number from x in `{& for x in s.num_rows &}`.

I'd like the id to be that of the value from the for loops

Any clue?

Thank you

Comment: Just use `{{ x }}`? By the way, this is not django template syntax.

Comment: whops its % not &. I'll try that

Comment: It not rendering the tables

Comment: It doesnt matter for django where its rendered in table or in div or anywhere. Its either your html not valid or you are looking at wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Like  Burhan Khalid said use {{ x }}. But iterating in templates doesn't work this way.
"Take a look at these template filters and tags, either of which is easy enough to include in your application.

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/

The advantage of these compared to the other solutions (passing in a range of numbers) is that, once installed, these will always be available to your templates and template authors, without having to explicitly pass a valid range through your view code."

See [Numeric for loop in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates). 
Once you have the "get_range" filter you could write your code something like this:

```
<div id="holder" onclick="dostuff()">
    <table id="table" bgcolor="{{s.color_hash}}">
        <tbody>
            {% for x in get_range(s.num_rows) %}
                <tr id="{{ x }}">
                    {% for y in get_range(s.num_columns) %}
                        <td id="c" height='{{s.height}}' width='{{s.width}}'></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```