# Django Template Loop from 0-100

Tags: django, for-loop

I have multiple online forms that I'm working on and there will be several pull down menus with different numeric ranges.

For example I need a simple template loop from 0 to 100 that will be used in an online form.

Is there something that does not require some custom views or such?

Was thinking something like this:

```
{% for i in x |range[0, 100] %}
  <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you be clarify your question?

Comment: I have multiple online forms that I'm working on and there will be several pull down menus with different numeric ranges.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numeric for loop in Django templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates)

Comment: Maxime, I saw that thread. It is from 2009 and I'm hoping that Django evolved since then and that there are some better solutions than some custom snippets for something so simple.

Comment: @WayBehind, if this thing does not exist (and it actually still doesn't), it's not because Django is bad, it's because it's not the template role to do such a thing. Watch the xjtian answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest approach would be to pass in a `range(0, 100)` in the response context through your view. You could also write your own `range` template filter, or search for an existing one on the web - I'm sure there are existing implementations out there.

Comment: +1 with passing range(0, 100) in the view! This is the easiest way.