# Django Template: How to modify the value in the for-loop tag?

Tags: python, django, templates, for-loop

What I want to do is simple: I want to display a HTML select tag which includes option tags with value 1971 ~ 2020.

The following is code snippet:

```
Year<select name="selected_year">
{% for i in "x"|rjust:"50" %}
    <option value="{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ forloop.counter }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

the {{forloop.counter}} will display 1 ~ 50.
my question is: how to display 1971 ~ 2020 instead?
any suggestion?

BTW, the for loop code is referenced from another question:
[Numeric for loop in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use the `|add` filter to modify each value:

```
<option value="{{ forloop.counter|add:1970 }}">{{ forloop.counter|add:1970 }}</option>
```

But don't do this. Use `range(1971, 2021)` in the view and pass that to the template.

Comment: oh my god, I really don't know this. I am still a newbie in Django world. thanks man! I have spent hours to search an answer = =.

Comment: why not do that? any special reason?