# Caught TypeError while rendering: 'int' object is not iterable in django template

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates, typeerror

I was trying to iterate a `list_length` in a for loop. The `list_length` is an `int` object which is passed as a context variable to the template. But when I try to do that it gives this `typeError`. Can someone help?

```
{% for i in list_length %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How do you wish to iterate `int` object ?. Try just `{{ i }}` in your template without `for` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are trying to print index of every row in the table. For that you have to iterate over a list of indices. Create this list in your django view

```
list = []
for i in range(0,list_length):
    list.append(i)
```

Then pass this list in your django template and iterate over it

```
{% for i in list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

A *list* itself may be iterable, but a single integer on its own is *not* a list.

If you want to iterate from zero up to an integer, you can use something like Python's `range(n)` to *create* an iterator for those values. That's for naked Python, Django appears to require a slightly more complex method, as per [Numeric for loop in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates).

Otherwise, you possibly need to iterate over the list itself rather than its length (depending on what you're trying to do and whether you need a list 'index' within the loop).

Comment: when i try `{% for i in range(list_length) %}` it gives  `TemplateSyntaxError  :Could not parse the remainder: '(list_length)' from 'range(list_length)'`

Comment: @user3496949, the key phrase there was 'like Python's range ...' :-) Have updated with a link to another SO question showing how to do same in Django, no use repeating that info here.