# Python web pages, PHP-style

Tags: php, python, html, preprocessor, web-frameworks

I have used Python and PHP a lot, but just out of curiosity, **is there a version of Python that uses a similar paradigm to PHP for dynamic creation of html pages**, i.e. like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<?py                        # similar to <?php ... ?>
for i in range(10):
    print '<div>Hello%i</div>' % i
?>

</body>
</html>
```

?

---

*Note 1: I'm **not** speaking about Django, Flask, Bottle, Twisted, etc. that don't use such syntax.*

*Note 2: The suggested code would be like this in PHP:*

```
<html>
<body>

<?php 
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{ 
    echo '<div>Hello' . $i . '</div>'; 
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This article might be useful for you http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/pythoninsidehtml.html

Comment: Exactly *what* are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: pylatte -> https://github.com/rucifer1217/pylatte does <-  what you want

Comment: You should take the hint from the fact that none of the frameworks do it this way. It's a really bad idea.

Comment: Yes you can create a sort of for loop in a django template, but I still don't understand what your question is about.

Comment: We all understand what you mean, we are just pointing out that no-one in the Python world thinks it's a good idea to write code that way.

Comment: I have used PHP once and I *don't* understand what you mean, are you trying to use variables in a template? for loops? The *exact* syntax you've shown above? Use the description part of your question to *describe* it

Comment: That still doesn't really explain what you hope to achieve.... [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1107737/1324033)

Comment: A Python Server Pages project that did this did exist, but has been dead for years. Again, take the hint.

Comment: @Sayse: it has nothing to do with the question you link.  What I want to achieve is to use some code *inside* HTML, in the same way PHP allows to use code *inside* HTML

Comment: I give up and agree with Daniel Roseman, Django has a template syntax, as do other python packages. Please read [ask]. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a version of Python that uses a similar paradigm to PHP for dynamic creation of html pages

No, python cannot be embedded in html like the way you want. The idea is to separate the view (html) from the code (python).

Have a look at how template engine works, they can allow fairly complex amount of *python code*.

Example with [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/):

```
    <ul>
        {% for user in users %}
            <li><a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

[Other](http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/pythoninsidehtml.html) solutions closer to what you want will *convert* the html to a python script that will produce the fully interpreted html. It's a bit of an overkill ...