# Django cycle into template ,ORM

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

I have a django view and a make a render html to return a ORM query some as

```
products.objects.all()
return render(request,'index.html',{"product":products})
```

I can make a render correctly from html page using a for cycle ,
the query of products  this return a code and product's quantity now my problem is how i can make  a cycle for print the same product twice o more depending of the product's quantity

I have sometime similar

```
{%for a in range({{product.quantity}})%}
```

but not is posible  make a render correctly of  template

Some idea how I should be make this cycle for into this template

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using (the code sample you have posted will not work at all) and the relevant models. As it is currently it's hard to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to treat Django's template language as if it's an `eval`, and your variable `{{product.quantity}}` will be replaced with an integer, resulting in your statement `for a in range(x)` being executed.

That's incorrect.

Django's template language is not Python. It is written in Python, and it's syntax resembles Python, but is not Python. You cannot use Python within it.

Django's template language does not have a native `range` [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates) for an example of how to approach this.