# Is it possible to show multiple times the same queryset on template?

Tags: django, django-templates

This is an odd question but I'd like to be able to show the same queryset multiple times on my template using different `{% for loops %}`, I'm trying to avoid copy pasting each `{% for loops %}`.

Let's say I have my **views.py** like this :

```
...
    chicken = Chicken.objects.filter(id=1)
    return render(request, 'chicken.html', {'chicken':chicken}
```

**chicken.html :** the example below is the one I'm avoiding.

```
<!-- {{ egg }} has the same value everywhere --> 

{% for egg in chicken %} <!-- has a different index than other loops -->
    <p id="egg_1">{{egg}}</p> 
{% endfor %}

{% for egg in chicken %}
    <p id="egg_2">{{egg}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for egg in chicken %}
    <p id="egg_3">{{egg}}</p>
{% endfor %}

...x52...
```

Is there a way to automatise this while having a different index on each loop ?

I'm searching for something like this :

```
{% for chicken x52 %}
    {% for egg in chicken %}
        <p id="egg_index">{{egg}}</p> <!-- each with different index -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example you have given, you could add a variable `loops` to the context:

```
chicken = Chicken.objects.filter(id=1)
loops = range(1, 53)
return render(request, 'chicken.html', {'chicken':chicken, 'loops': loops}
```

Then loop through `loops` in the template:

```
{% for loop in loops %}
  {% for egg in chicken %} <!-- has a different index than other loops -->
    <p id="egg_{{ loop }}">{{egg}}</p> 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't want to add a variable to the context, there are some different approaches suggested on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates), some hackier than others.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for :)