# How to Include while loop inside template file in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to render block of html code 5 times in template file. Like in php I tried something like below,

```
{% extends 'stories/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<h1>This is rating page</h1>

<section class='rating-widget'>
  {% with count = 0 %}
  {% while count < 5: %}
      <div class='rating-stars text-center'>
          <ul class='stars'>
              <li class='star selected' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
                  <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star selected' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
                  <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star selected' title='Good' data-value='3'>
                  <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star selected' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
                  <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star selected' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
                  <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
        {% count += 1 %}
      {% endwhile %}
  {% endwith %}
</section>
```

But I couldn't get expected result. It gives me syntax error "'with' expected at least one variable assignment". Is this possible or what is the proper way to implement this kind of loop in django?

Comment: You can't increment variables in the Django template language. The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates) I linked to has several suggestions. For looping 5 times, `{% for i in 'xxxxx' %}` is simplest. For larger numbers, I like the suggestion of the `times` filter.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks. It worked and simple. There are lot of things to learn :).

Answer (score -2):

You need to remove the spaces between the `count = 0` part, due to the way the `{% with %}` template tag parses variable assignment.

Comment: That would fix the issue with the `with` tag, then you'll immediately get an error on the next line `{% while count < 5: %}`. The key point is that you can't do this kind of thing in the Django template language.

Comment: @ptr Thanks for your answer.