# alternative to range function in django template. TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder

Tags: django, templates, range

In template, I try to use:

```
{% for i in range(object.punctuation) %}
    <i class="material-icons">star</i> 
{% endfor %}
```

Where object.punctuation is an integer with the rating that the object has. Visually this punctuation needs to be represented with stars. But I get:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(object.punctuation)' from 'range(object.punctuation)'
```

As cited in:
https://jbmoelker.github.io/jinja-compat-tests/functions/range/#stop
looks like range function in jinja has problems with django integration.
Is there an alternative to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Jinja because *you are not using Jinja*. You are using Django template language, which as all the documentation including the tutorial explains, does not allow you to call functions with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can have a variable

```
my_range = range(object.punctuation)
context['my_range'] = my_range
```

and then pass it to template from context. Then loop over as follows:

```
{% for i in my_range %}
    <i class="material-icons">star</i> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Got amazed cause it worked for a single object. 
But now I'm dealing with modifying each object item data, since it is the result of looping from a query list

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's correction helped.
Found my solution here: 
  [Numeric for loop in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates)

```
{% with ''|center:object.punctuation as range %}
    {% for _ in range %}
    <i class="material-icons">star</i>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```