# Iterating over the value of a form in Django

Tags: django

I have a form, that accepts a number. On submission of the form, this number is redirected to another html page from the django views.py. Here, how do I iterate over the number that I have received? When I try with the below, it says `'int' object is not iterable`

```
{% for i in N %}
 <p>{{i}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: N here is the number received from the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is because a number can not be iterated over. In python you would have to use `range(N)` like this:

```
for i in range(N):
    print(i)
```

The template language from django does not have a `for .. in range ..` functionality. What you are looking for is a custom filter that you would have to load.

You would have to create a new file called `my_filters.py` and register all the filters you need.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='times')
def times(number):
    return range(number)
```

In the templates use this:

```
{% load my_filters %}
{% for i in N|times %}
    <p>{{i}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797728/10041092)