# Enumerate number in django template

Tags: django, templates

It's a question by curiosity :

So i have 4 types of choice for field of a model.

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    Cat_One = (("b", "Big"), ("s", "Small"),("a","very small"),("x","xtra small"))
    dateCreation = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=800)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    catOne = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Cat_One, blank=True, null=True)
```

so i can pass the choice to the django template :

```
{% for choice in  cat_One %}
```

...
And iterate.

But i would like to know , how to iterate from 1 to  4 without passing something to the django template ?

Is there a way to do :

```
{% for number in [1,2,3,4] %}
```

or something with a forloop counter ?

regards

Comment: you mean slicing `cat_One|slice:"0:4"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj you gave me the answer it's possible to make a {% for num in slice:"0:4" %} in django. I wanted to know how to iterate numbers without giving anything to the django template.

Comment: Are the answers here perhaps helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `Thing` model:

```
@property
def numbers(self):
    return [1,2,3,4]
```

Then in your template you could do something like:

```
{% for number in thing.numbers %}
<li>{{ number }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks I've learned something but i would like to know how to iterate from 1 to 4 without passing something to the django template.

Comment: You should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates