# Creating multiple annotations using a for loop

Tags: python, django

Here is my code:

```
 phones = Customer.objects.filter(active=True).values('name')\
        .annotate(count = Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=model_list[0]))
        .annotate(count1 = Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=model_list[1]))
        .annotate(count2 = Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=model_list[2]))
        .annotate(count3 = Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=model_list[3]))
        .annotate(count4 = Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=model_list[4]))
    ........
```

**html**

```
{% if phones %}
    {% for phone in phones %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ phone.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ phone.count  }}</td>
        <td>{{ phone.count1  }}</td>
        <td>{{ phone.count2  }}</td>
        <td>{{ phone.count3  }}</td>
        <td>{{ phone.count4  }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% enfif %}
```

My `model_list` still has many models. What should I do to simplify these using for loop?

If my `model_list` has `100` models, this will be very complicated.

I've tried this:

```
for i in range(len(model_list)):
    phone= Customer.objects.filter(active=True).values('name')\
        .annotate(count = Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=model_list[i]))
```

**html**

```
{% if phones %}
{% for phone in phones %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ phone.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ phone.count  }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But the result is not what I want, because I only get one of the data.
For example :`model_list[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Do like this to query for counts:

```
phones = Customer.objects.filter(active=True).values('name')

for idx, model in enumerate(model_list):
    counts = {'count%s' % idx : Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=model)}
    phones = phones.annotate(**counts)
```

Then you would need to pass a range of models to the template (say in `models_idx_range` as context parameter `models_idx_range=range(models_count)`) and iterate over counts:

```
{% if phones %}
{% for phone in phones %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ phone.name }}</td>
    {% for idx in models_idx_range %}
        <td>{{ getattr(phone, 'count%s' % idx) }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I get an error with this.`not all arguments converted during string formatting`. This error point to the line `counts = { ......`

Comment: Of cause, there was a typo in `'count%s' % idx`. Now fixed

Comment: I know how your code works but I get this error: `Could not parse the remainder: '(models_count)' from 'range(models_count)'`

Comment: It seems that django templates [do not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates) that so you need a workaround. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a django expert but i think this is your error:

```
phone = Customer.objects.filter(active=True).values('name')

for i in range(len(model_list)):
     phone= phone.annotate(count = Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=model_list[i]))
```

You always override your phone with the last value from the for-loop

Comment: This would not work as this replaces `N` aggregations (`count`, `count1` etc) with only one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
phones = Customer.objects.filter(active=True).values('name')\
    .annotate(count = Count('phone',filter=Q(phone__model__icontains=[i for i in model_list]))
```

Comment: How should i display it in html?

Comment: This would not work. If you pass the list to `__icontains` the query would not find anything.