# How to loop a <span> using template tag in django? condition for the loop comes from database and its of type integer

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Getting an error when try to loop in django template, {% for i in obj.rating %}, where obj.rating is integer value.

i tried to add range() {% for i in range(obj.rating) %}, but its not working.

```
{% for i in obj.rating %}
  <span class="fa fa-star blue-star" id="star1"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Various solutions are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{% for i in i|rjust:obj.rating %}
  <span class="fa fa-star blue-star" id="star1">some text</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried, but in that loop statement obj.rating is returning None i think(hence for i in i, runes for 4 times), but when in put {{ obj.rating }} inside loop it shows the value. but not in the for loop statement why so?

Comment: I don't know why, did you write the code correctly without any syntax error?

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. please edit i to "i".
{% for i in "x"|ljust:obj.rating %}
     <span class="fa fa-star blue-star" id="star1"></span>
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

In your python code make a list like below and then pass it to template to iterate over it.

```
list = []
for item in range(rating):
    list.append(item)
```

make sure to end the loop by

```
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sorry its just typing mistake i used {% endfor %} in my html page

Comment: no its not. its showing 'int' object is not iterable. obj.rating is integer value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192660/discussion-between-saran-prasad-and-chirag-soni).