# for loop with an integer in django's templates tags

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django template `{{review.stars}}` is an integer from 1 to 5, but instead of showing a simple number I want to show a number of star icons equal to the `{{review.stars}}` integer.

I should write something like:

```
for n in range(1, review.stars+1):
  add star icon
```

but obviously I can't write something like that in Django template tags.
What's the pythonic way to run a loop a variable number of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the range from the view to the template and then loop through that. Referencing [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107777/9366940):

View:

```py
render_to_response('template.html', {..., 'stars': range(review.stars), ...}, ...)
```

Template:

```py
{% for n in stars %}
    # add star icon
{% endfor %}
```