# Nested for loops with numeric values in Django

Tags: python, django-templates

I have a 2D List as follows:

`my_list = [["2","","4"],["3","",""],["1","1",""]]`

In Python, we can iterate over the above-mentioned list if we want to know the index of items in the following way.

```
   for row in range(len(my_list)):
       for column in range(len(my_list[row])):
           print("Item at position ", row, column)
           print(my_list[row][column)
```

I am trying to implement the above approach in Django Template as well. I can access the element directly in the following manner:

`for row in my_list`

The above approach works perfectly, but I need to access index and that's why I need Nested Numeric Loops:

I tried the following approach given in this link: 
[Numeric Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates)

I made a solution mentioned below but it is not printing anything

```
{% for row in '0123' %}
    {% for column in my_list.row %}
        <p> {{my_list.row.column}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong in the above code & is there any simpler approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need `forloop.parentloop` & `forloop.counter`.

```
{% for row in my_list %}
    {% for column in row %}
        <p> {{forloop.parentloop.counter}} {{ forloop.counter }} </p>
        <p> {{ column }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)**