# How to add links dynamically in html files in django?

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

For my project, I'm searching for articles on google news based on keyword input by the user, I want to display these links obtained from the search on my results page.

this is my result.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Result{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h3><a href="{{link_to_post}}" target="_blank">Reported Url</a></h3>
    <div>Post Content: <br>{{content}}</div>

    <h3>News articles related to your query:</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for key, value  in articles.items %}

    <li><a href="{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Back to Home Page</a>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

But the links do not work and I get the page not found error, since these links are not contained in urls.py.
How can I link these urls correctly?

thank you

Comment: there are some syntax errors

Comment: @Blackdoor I edited my question, fixed the syntax, How do I attach the links correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem I had to replace "./" in the article to the homepage of the site I was refering to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute python code inside Django templates.
Check out this thread: [Numeric for loop in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates)

Comment: I fixed that part, but how do I make the links work properly?