# How to for loop from a number to number in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I try to do this:

```
  {% for post in posts %}
  {% if forloop.counter 15>=30  %}
    <div style="background-color: #9999;" class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 100%;">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}"><img style="height: 200px; width: 330px;" src="{{ post.mainimage.url }}" class="card-img" alt="..."></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="ph">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }} , {{ post.xnumber }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.version }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.category }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_added }}</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <hr >
  {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

and it gives me an error:
[the photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUzTe.png)

**What I'm trying to do is make the repetition start at 15 and end or =  at 30 **

I searched a lot and couldn't find what I wanted
So **please** help me
lan = **python django**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numeric for loop in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates)

Comment: you can compare forloop.counter like this  ==> `forloop.counter>15 and forloop.counter<=30 ` in you for loop thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this

```
{% if forloop.counter>15 and forloop.counter<=30  %}
```

Comment: i fix it thx 
its like that 
`{% if forloop.counter <= 15 %}`